# How to access unique pairs from a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a list `L = [a, b, c]` and I want to pick all unique non-repeating pairs: `[a, b], [a, c], [b, c]`. If I simply use the member function, it, of course, picks every permutation, so I have to have a predicate

```
pick_pair(List, X, Y) :-
    member(X, List),
    member(Y, List),
    \+ X = Y.
```

And to access the members I gather all the pairs into a list by using another predicate

```
unique_pairs(List, Result) :-
    findall([X, Y], pick_pair(List, X, Y), Result).
```

and only then I acess the resulting list, but it generates `[[a, b], [a, c], [b, a], [b, c], [c, a], [c, b]]`. I tried to get rid of the pairs that are just a reverse of pairs that were already there by `list_to_set` but `[a, b]` and `[b, a]` do not unify on default, so they're considered to be not equal and therefore belong to the set. I would somehow need to overload the unification for that function or something like that.

My question is:

Can we just access pairs in a list? Something like `my_pairs(X, Y, L)` which would assign the pair elements directly to `X` and `Y`. And if there is no such predicate, how can we make a list of the unique pairs so that we can access its elements by using `member(X, List)`?

*The problem is, by the way, equivalent to getting all the combinations of length two.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use a custom variant of `select`:

```
unique_pairs(L, E1, E2) :-
    select_forward(E1, L, L0),
    member(E2, L0).
    
select_forward(E, [H|T], F) :-
    select_forward_(T, H, E, F).
    
select_forward_(T, H, H, T).
select_forward_([H|T], _, E, F) :-
    select_forward_(T, H, E, F).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- unique_pairs([a,b,c], E1, E2).
E1 = a,
E2 = b ;
E1 = a,
E2 = c ;
E1 = b,
E2 = c ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating combinations of *m* things taken *n* at a time is easy in Prolog:

```
combination( 0 , _      , []     ) .
combination( N , [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- N > 0, N1 is N-1, combination(N1,Xs,Ys).
combination( N , [_|Xs] ,    Ys  ) :- N > 0, combination(N,Xs,Ys).
```

Once you have that, your `pick_pair/2` become just:

```
pick_pair( Xs, P ) :- combination(2,Xs,P) .
```

You can also construct combinations with doing arithmetic: you just need to pass a list of the desired length containing variables -- that's just this:

```
combination( _      , []     ) .
combination( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- combination(Xs,Ys).
combination( [_|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- combination(Xs,[Y|Ys]).
```

With this implementation, if the second argument is completely uninstantiated, it will generate *all* combinations of any length from 0 through the length of the source list. And if the first argument is uninstantiated.... it will likely generate a [theoretically] infinite set of results.

With this implementatio, your `pick_pair/2` becomes something like

```
pick_pair( Xs, [P,Q] ) :- combination(Xs, [P,Q] ).
```

Or maybe

```
pick_pair( Xs, P ) :- length(P,2), combination(Xs,P).
```